# How to disable all animations, transitions?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to disable all animations, transitions in VSCode? For example either through CSS or 
"\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\electron-browser\bootstrap\index.html"

Answer (score 2):

As of VS Code 1.30, there is no built-in way to do this (but there also aren't really that many animations).

The feature request is currently being tracked [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/64822)

Comment: Ugh? With custom CSS it should be possible to do.

Comment: This feature request is now tracked here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/124644

Please up-vote.

Comment: The issue was not "up" voted sufficiently to become worked on by Microsoft. Having animations in a working programmer's editor is like having tassels on a carpenter's hammer; if the programmer doesn't notice it then it is fine but when they do it is annoying. I can't imagine a real programmer thinking that feature was beneficial.

Comment: There is one animation that is annoying and useless, when you delete many files in a folder, it shows you how it removes one by one. This is not an professional behavior, but a game like one.